# Two projects in one workspace - sharing resources

Tags: ios, xcode

Is this possible to have two projects A nad B in a workspace and use resources from B in A.
I keep finding answers about static library, but if this is necessary?

Comment: Did you do any research into your question beforehand such as googling "xcode workspace" or something to that affect? Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 before asking another question.

Comment: A static library isn't difficult or time consuming so why are you trying to avoid one? Also what type of resourced do you mean? Code or images/strings?

Answer (score -1):

I thought it's not possible.

- By using target you can use resource form B in A.